# Displaying only the first record for multiple entries in a 5 minute period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which displays rows in sets, each row set will have two records identified by 1 and 2. it is basically the In and Out Time. Sometimes the user will punch data multiple times. For example, when he is punching 'in', he may punch it multiple times just to make sure, but actually he is supposed to punch it only 1 time. While punching 'out', he may punch it again multiple times just to make sure, but actually he is supposed to punch it only 1 time. The time is captured on each entry. I need to configure the below query to get only the first time entry or record for multiple entries. To be more precise, if there are multiple entries in a 5 minute period, then only the first record to be displayed ignoring the rest in the particular 5 minute period.

```
SELECT TransactionID, TrDate, Time1, Tr_Serial, Port, UnitNo, UserPIN,Finger,
      IP, UnitName, Tr_Description,
      CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userpin, TrDate
      ORDER BY trdate, time1) % 2 = 0
      THEN '2'
      ELSE '1'
      END Tr_Type
      FROM (
      SELECT row_number() OVER (
      ORDER BY datetime) TransactionID, cast([datetime] AS date) TrDate, cast(
      [datetime] AS time) Time1, [eventserial] Tr_Serial, '1' Port, [READERID]
      UnitNo, [EVENTID] Tr_Type, [USERID] UserPIN, '1' Finger, 'NA' IP, [
      READERNAME] UnitName, [EVENTNAME] Tr_Description
      FROM [BBC].[dbo].[BBC_LOG]) A
      WHERE Tr_Type = 47 OR Tr_Type = 55
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TransactionID, TrDate, MIN(Time1), Tr_Serial, Port, UnitNo, UserPIN,Finger,
  IP, UnitName, Tr_Description,
  CASE WHEN Min(ROW_NUMBER()) OVER (PARTITION BY userpin, TrDate
  ORDER BY trdate, time1) % 2 = 0
  THEN '2'
  ELSE '1'
  END Tr_Type
  FROM (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (
  ORDER BY datetime) TransactionID, cast([datetime] AS date) TrDate, cast(
  [datetime] AS time) Time1, [eventserial] Tr_Serial, '1' Port, [READERID]
  UnitNo, [EVENTID] Tr_Type, [USERID] UserPIN, '1' Finger, 'NA' IP, [
  READERNAME] UnitName, [EVENTNAME] Tr_Description
  FROM [BBC].[dbo].[BBC_LOG]) A
  WHERE Tr_Type = 47 OR Tr_Type = 55
```

Try this 
not sure what your output is but i know you need Min() on your datetime, to get the first date/ time i.e the first the user clocked in with